# Wave to alaw using NAudio?

Tags: c#, naudio

Hello guys i'm trying to convert wave file to al is there any person familiar with NAudio?

```
        WaveStream ws = new WaveFileReader(waveFile);
        WaveFormatConversionStream stream =  new WaveFormatConversionStream(WaveFormat.CreateALawFormat(11025,1), ws);
        WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(outputFile, stream);
```

I was trying this one but acm shows error {"AcmNotPossible calling acmStreamOpen"}

Answer (score 0):

You can't always perform conversions like this in a single step. For example if your input audio is 44.1kHz stereo, then you need to first go to mono, then downsample to 11.025kHz, then you can do the mu law. Check [my article here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/501521/How-to-convert-between-most-audio-formats-in-NET) for further explanation.